# Error code with javascript, how to change it?

Tags: javascript

Either my javascript or my template is broken.

This is my javascript to change error messages. I cannot change my template, because it is not accessible.

> $(function() { 
>       $.ajaxSetup({complete: function() { 
>             $("errorExplanation:contains('1')").html('1 error has occurred');;}}) });

This is the part of the website that refuses to be translated:

[The code of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZYKp.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Substitute `$(".errorExplanation:contains('1')")` , for `$("errorExplanation:contains('1')")`; note `.`

Comment: Works, thank you very much.